# Difference in unqualified and namespaced keys?

Tags: clojure

In specs guide it says libraries tend to use unqualified keys, I can't determine the difference by looking at the docs.

Comment: If you are refering to "docs" and "guides" and ask for help to understand them better, please link or even better properly quote the source.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the term "qualified keywords" versus "unqualified keywords" is the current recommended names for these ideas, but many people still use the terms "namespaced keywords" or "keywords with namespaces" instead of "qualified keywords".  Those three terms are synonyms.

A qualified keyword contains a slash character (/), with the qualifier before the slash, which is often, but *need not be*, the name of a Clojure namespace, e.g. `:this.is.a.qualifer/some-keyword`.

An unqualified keyword (synonym "keyword without a namespace") contains no slash character, e.g. `:some-keyword`.

Search for "keywords" on this Clojure reference documentation page: https://clojure.org/reference/reader

Comment: First time I've heard the un/qualified terminology.  It's a good way of clarifying the independence of qualified keywords from the presence/absence of a namespace. Thanks for pointing that out.